# How does Miller survive the acceleration in The Expanse?

Tags: physics, the-expanse-2015

In The Expanse, when Miller is

> on Eros, accelerating towards Earth, chased by the Rocinante

we can guess there's a fair bit of acceleration and plenty of G's

> as per the crew of the Rocinante having trouble keeping up. Even Eros is accelerating further still

yet Miller is unaffected by this acceleration. Why? Is it

> some undisclosed property of the protomolecule

that's able to dampen inertia?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both the novels and the TV show mention that the protomolecule system on Eros is able to eliminate inertia. When the still under-construction enormous LDS Church-commissioned generation ship *Nauvoo* is commandeered and used as a bomb to try to destroy Eros, the protomolecule quite rapidly impels the asteroid out of the way. Miller is on the surface of Eros at the time, witnesses the *Nauvoo* missing, realizes what has just happened, and explicitly reflects that he felt no acceleration. Other characters understand inertial-dampening to be within the abilities of the system built by the protomolecule.

Comment: This is the final nail in the coffin for any notion of The Expanse being a hard scifi setting. What I enjoyed most about the series was that it took the notion of the concepts of inertia and acceleration seriously if its solutions to the problems they posed were often ludicrous (spin gravity, anyone?). Then in the middle of the climax it throws all of that out the airlock, lampshades the G-force, forgets completely about conservation of momentum, and becomes science fantasy with extra steps.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish If the treatment of Eros bothers you, then I suggest you may not be too happy with what comes after.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish, even with the protomolecule shenanigans, The Expanse is a harder scifi setting than 99.9999% than anything else. Even 2001 A Space Odyssey had the monolith with the FTL star gate.

Comment: @approachingdarknessfish What would actually constitute hard sci fi then? Not Asimov, Niven, or Clarke, with those criteria. Must be stuff I’ve never read nor seen.

Comment: I wasn't bothered that it broke the laws of physics as we understand them. I was bothered that it broke the rules _of its own setting_ 90% of the way through the book with, afaict, no foreshadowing.

Comment: Now that's it's been established that the protomolecule can do these sorts of things, maybe the following books will feel "hard" to me again. But after 400+ pages of being told over and over again that familiar physics determines what is and is not possible in this setting, the ending with Eros felt like narrative cheating, and it divested me from the story.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish I can appreciate the enjoyment of hard SF. But "No foreshadowing" seems a smidge inattentive to the weirdiness of the "protomolecule"... a synthetic form of life able to hijack entire ecosystems under the correct circumstances is a technology made by someone(s) playing at a very different level than dinky hairless apes riding around on fusion reactors.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Yeah.. the protomolecule is a (quite inscrutable) "character" across the series. I think maybe *Nemesis Games* is the only *Expanse* novel  where it (or the efforts of its makers) is not somehow in play. For what it is worth.

Comment: @Lexible Personally I feel that the difference in level between "hairless apes riding around on fusion reactors" and "the ability to hijack an entire ecosystem" is next to nothing compared to the difference between "the ability to hijack an entire ecosystem" and "the ability to _disregard interia_".

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish I think the closest we have seen in a few billion years of evolution to a *anything* coming close to hijacking an ecosystem is aerobic respiration and the oxygen revolution, but neither aerobic organisms, nor mitochondria effect the kind of totalizing repurposing evidenced by the protomolecule. Not taking what it did with Eros as evidence of playing on another level is not paying attention to how profoundly ahead of the game it and its makers were.

Comment: "What would actually constitute hard sci fi then? Not Asimov, Niven, or Clarke, with those criteria." -- Some of Niven, maybe.  Ever read *The Bowl of Heaven* and sequelae?  Even has the 10% C limit on ramscoops.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I agree with you, but what about Gibson's *The Bridge* trilogy, and the *Blue Ant* trilogy? None of those are space-opera though . . . maybe *Seveneves*?

Comment: @Lexible Haven't read those.  I have a budget, and even if I didn't, they can publish faster than I can read.

Comment: @ZeissIkon May I recommend your public library? Lord knows mine *hooks me up!*

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish In my copy of Leviathan Wakes, there is an interview with the authors at the end where they explicitly state that they did *not* intend the books to be hard sci-fi. Besides, the fact that it’s so jarring and shocking  that the physics rules get broken is exactly the point - it’s unprecedented. In fact, in later books a character takes advantage of the fact that people could believe the protomolecule could do *anything* and therefore don’t investigate something that should clearly be impossible.

Comment: @Lexible I've never found a library that will lend me a free weekend when I need it...

Comment: @ZeissIkon Audiobooks are proof both of a benign god's existence and love.

Comment: I can't listen to audiobooks.  Just a personal quirk.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish I'm ok with the hardness/non-hardness of it. The setting is initially _hardish_ , and then humans meet something that's much softer. The end result is not hard sci-fi, but that was never the promise in the first place.